# Does Sion minimax require choice?

Tags: lo.logic, nonlinear-optimization

Is the axiom of choice (or equivalent) required to establish Sion's minimax theorem?

H. Komiya's elementary
[proof](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kmj/1138038812)
does not seem not to use any transfinite induction or choice axiom. Is this really the case, or is it implicit there in some sneaky form?

The other elementary proofs --- 
[Kindler](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30037472?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)'s
and
[Hichem Ben-El-Mechaiekh and Robert W. Dimand](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.118.07.636?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)'s do use Zorn or Hahn-Banach (which has a non-trivial relation to choice, discussed elsewhere on this site at length).

Comment: This is an expanded version of a https://math.stackexchange.com/ question that went unanswered for a few days.

Comment: Which question from stackexchange? Your link directs to the general webpage..

Comment: oops, here it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353284/minimax-without-choice